# Executable not rebuilt but object files recompiled

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Building a basic C++ project with Visual Studio 2012. When I make changes to source files:

- the corresponding object files are compiled
- the .tlog files for the compiler are updated
- the PDB file is updated
- the .tlog files for the linker however are not changed
- the linker claims `All outputs are up-to-date.` and does not build a new executable.

The only way to get the executable to be built is deleting it. It seems something with the tracking system is wrong and I was wondering if anyone can shed some light on this issue.

Here is the msbuild output after I change two files, full paths and some other stuff omitted (this output is for the VS2010 toolset, but 2012 behaves the same):

```
 1>Target "ClCompile" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.targets"...
  Using "CL" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Win32, Version=4.0.0.0...
  Task "CL"
    Read Tracking Logs:
     cl.read.1.tlog
     CL.2520.read.1.tlog
     ...
    Outputs for ....
     XXX.OBJ
     YYY.OBJ
     ...
    xxx.cpp will be compiled as xxx.cpp was modified...
    yyy.cpp will be compiled as yyy.cpp was modified...
    Write Tracking Logs:
     cl.write.1.tlog
     CL.2520.write.1.tlog
     ...
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\CL.exe ....
    Tracking command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\Tracker.exe ....
    xxx.cpp
    yyy.cpp
  Done executing task "CL".
1>Done building target "ClCompile" in project "xxx.vcxproj".
```

so far, so good. Now the linker kicks in (well, it doesn't):

```
1>Target "Link" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.targets"....
  Using "Link" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Win32, Version=4.0.0.0...
  Task "Link"
    Using cached output dependency table built from:
    link.write.1.tlog
    Using cached input dependency table built from:
     ink.read.1.tlog
    Outputs for ....
     MY.EXE
     MY.PDB
    All outputs are up-to-date.
  Done executing task "Link".
  Task "Message"
    xxx.vcxproj -> my.exe
  Done executing task "Message".
1>Done building target "Link" in project "xxx.vcxproj".
```

Comment: Interestingly, I have the same problem, but the solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: What are your Intermediate/Output directories set to?

Comment: $(IntDir) is $(VmRoot)Temp\$(ProjectName)\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\, where $(VmRoot) is the root of the development environment, and $(VmRoot)Temp is not equal to %TMP% or %TEMP%. I'm currently testing the hypothesis that the restriction also applies to subdirectories of _all_ directories named "Temp".

Comment: Good point, maybe it's just string matching on lowercase( "temp" ) or so indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking all options we have in the property sheets one-by-one, it seems the sole source of this problem is that we have the intermediate directory set to a directory on another drive. We always do out of source builds in %TEMP%, and most of the time the projects reside on another drive.

Filed a bug report [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760370/linker-does-not-link-if-intermediate-directory-with-changed-object-files-is-on-another-drive) including simple steps that reproduce the problem. Hopefully this gets fixed soon. Current soltuion is to set IntDir to a direcyory on the same drive as the project.

**UPDATE**

The bug report filed for this issue was closed as 'by design': it seems the Intermediate Directory should not be %TEMP% or %TMP% or any subdirectory of those. Disturbing, but at least I know what was wrong now.