# Visual Studio / MSBUILD does not update .lib files when sources are updated

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio solution with a library project let's call it `libFoo`, and an executable project - let's call it `Bar` which depends on `libFoo`.

When I change, for example, `libFoo/bar.cpp` and attemp to build `libFoo` then Visual Studio compiles my bar.cpp file, but does not re-generate the library `libFoo.lib`, saying that it is already up to date.

I checked the system clock. I also verified that the modification time of the `bar.obj` file is actually updated and that the library is older than the obj. But it still does not re-create the library.

The actual solution actually consists of around 100 projects, some of them are libraries and some of them are executables. The problem happens on the computers of 3 of my team members. The rest are unaffected. We have no idea why it happens, and how to fix it... or weather it might happen to the other team memebers.

I were not able to re-produce it by creating my own small solution with a library and an executable that depends on it. So I believe that this is some combination of an environment problem and a problem with our solution/project files.

Thanks,
Alex.

**Edit**

The solution was created on Visual Studio 2010 and developed on VS2010 for the past years, until we started using VS2012. The problem happens for users having both VS2010 and VS2012 installed. The solution is a VS2012 solution now, and the projects use the VS2010 platform toolkit.

When we started using VS2012, our team migrated the solution but we left the "platform toolkit" for all the C++ projects to be that of VS2010, to allow compatibility of our code with the other teams still using VS2010.

Google did not reveal any plausible solution. Although it did reveal the fact that other people also encountered similar problems.

Comment: Might be a stretch, but are your .lib files somehow in source control and therefore read-only?

Comment: Have you diffed the project/solution files between the people for whom this works those who it's broken?

Comment: It is identical. It happens when we get a clean-copy from the source control.

Comment: is libFoo a static library? I want to confirm that you are not referring to the .lib created with a dll project

Comment: Does everybody have the same installation level ( i.e Visual Studio Service packs ).  Also, did you have any other versions of VS on your system. If so were they installed in the order that they were released.  I have seen erroneous msbuild behaviors when installing versions out of order.

Comment: @allen, it is a static library.

Comment: @RobGoodwin, it seems that we found the difference. See the edit.

Comment: @RobGoodwin, The difference still does not explain how do I solve the problem. We DO need VS2012 in our computers, and we do wish to compile the existing code of the other teams that work with VS2010 and we do not wish to break compatibility. 

If you have any idea for a solution, please share it.

Comment: @Alex I have them both in my machine as well and MSBuild works as expected.  I have seen problems if they were installed out of order.  2012 before 2010.  I also had msbuild problems with the beta of 2012.  I ended up having to remove it and did not try it again until the official release came.  At that point, the msbuild problems were rectified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that we have encountered the same problem as the person who asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182203/executable-not-rebuilt-but-object-files-recompiled) question. There is also a [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/636271/linker-skipped-when-building-when-intermediate-directory-points-into-temp-folder) on Microsoft Connect.

To make things short - our intermediate folder was the same as our %temp% folder on some configurations. We solved the problem by modifying the intermediate folder of all our Visual C++ projects.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the project-property for "General\Target Name" and "Librarian\Output File" match, and that they match for all configurations.
It's worth checking the above on the "Librarian\Command Line" page also.

Comment: They do not match. The target name is $(ProjectName) and the output name is $(OutDir)$(ProjectName).lib

Can the target name be a full path?

Comment: Well.. I checked it. They do match. The target name is $(ProjectName) and the extension is .lib.

In the librarian settings the output path is $(OutDir)$(ProjectName).lib

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is DIFF'ing the log (and *.tlog) files from a working and non-working build.