# Visual Studio 2012 doesn't build project on run when its dependencies change

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm having a rather weird problem with Visual Studio 2012 lately:

- Project A (C++ DLL) references project B (C++ static lib). No CLR.
- Project A is set as my startup project (it has a debug command line set).
- After changing a file in project B and hitting CTRL+F5, VS2012 **doesn't build project A** before launching it. It **does build project B**!

Research steps I've already taken:

- After changing a file in project C, which is not referenced by either A or B, CTRL+F5 builds neither A nor B. This is expected.
- After changing a file in project A itself, CTRL+F5 builds A. This is expected.
- I've been able to reproduce this problem with project A' and dependency B'.
- Configuration Manager: all projects are set to be built in my working configuration.
- VS options:

  - "On Run, when projects are out of date:" = "Always build".
  - "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" is checked. Without it, it just build my entire huge solution when running project A, which is hardly what I want.

I should also note that we recently **upgraded from Visual Studio 2010** (with which we did not have this problem).

I'm fresh out of ideas. Anyone?

Comment: _After changing a file in project A itself, CTRL+F5 builds B. This is expected_ That is completely unexpected to me. From what you describe B has no dependency on A. Therefore any change in A should not cause a rebuild in B.

Comment: @stonemetal, you are absolutely correct. This was a typo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that this is the same problem described by these questions:

- [Visual Studio / MSBUILD does not update .lib files when sources are updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583703/visual-studio-msbuild-does-not-update-lib-files-when-sources-are-updated)
- [Executable not rebuilt but object files recompiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182203/executable-not-rebuilt-but-object-files-recompiled)

Solution: The intermediate folder for any VS project is not allowed to be under %TEMP% or %TMP%, and also may not be named "temp" (or maybe even contain the substring "temp"?).