# cmake executable doesn't get rebuilt

Tags: build, cmake, post-build-event, rebuild, post-build

I have a project structure as follows. A.dll depends on B.exe, B.exe depends on custom target C. The custom target C generates some files, which B.exe packages in an archive as a post build step on target B.

When I first build A.dll, since it is the first time B.exe gets built and as a post build step myArchieve.a gets built. From then on if I build the A.dll, B.exe doesn't get rebuilt, since it's an executable and it exists because of a previous build. The problems because of this are :

1. I always have a stale executable

2. If I make some changes to C and trigger a build of A.dll, cmake just rebuilds C and A. It doesn't rebuild B.exe and as a result it missed the archieve step and my archieve never gets updated.

Is there a solution to this problem ? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182203/executable-not-rebuilt-but-object-files-recompiled) link already and doesn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a conceptual problem with your setup: The packaging should not be a post-build step.

Instead you should use [`add_custom_command`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/add_custom_command.html) for the packaging and have that command `DEPENDS` on both the target that builds `B.exe` and the output files from your custom target `C`.

Comment: This won't work because add_custom_command's documentation clearly states that the custom command is given as a rule to target which uses its output files as source file. My output i.e. "myArchieve.a " isn't being used as a source by any target. Hence this custom command won't be added on any target.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite newbie with CMake and had a similar issue with exec not being rebuilt. I share my solution hopefully this will be helpful for future readers.

Note: The following solution was tested using VS 2017 with the new built in CMake support, so no solution is generated. Only the folder is loaded where the top-level CMakeLists.txt is found.

The folder structure would be:

```
.
└── A
    ├── B
    │   └── main.cpp
    ├── A.cpp
    └── A.h
```

You could create a sub folder for B:

```
# Content of "B/CMakeLists.txt"
project(B)

add_executable( BExec main.cpp)
add_custom_command(TARGET BExec 
                   PRE_BUILD
                   COMMAND cmake -E cmake_autogen ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/CMakeFiles/BExec_autogen.dir Debug)
```

And then you could do the following in A:

```
# Content of CMakeLists.txt for A
project(A)
add_subdirectory(B)

add_library(A A.cpp A.h)
add_dependencies(A BExec)
```

Every time you change the code in main.cpp, A.cpp or A.h, it will rebuild the library and the exec as well. Maybe not the most elegant, but working solution.